# selenium-webdriver, chromedriver: "ElementNotVisibleError"

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using NodeJS, with the selenium-webdriver and chromedriver dependencies. I'm having a little bit of difficulty troubleshooting why I can't get the `WebDriver.wait()` method to cooperate, as I would expect it to.

```
require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

...

driver.findElement(By.css(userSelector)).sendKeys(accountUsername);
driver.findElement(By.css(userNextButton)).click();

driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(passwordSelector))).then(function() {
    driver.findElement(By.css(passwordSelector)).sendKeys(accountPassword);
    driver.findElement(By.css(passwordNextButton)).click();
});

...
```

Can you please help me to troubleshoot why I'm getting an "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible" error message as the result of this? I can use the `WebDriver.sleep()` method to reach the desired outcome, but really just want to understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to answer this one on my own, after a lot of lost hair.

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(passwordSelector)));
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.css(passwordSelector)))).sendKeys(accountPassword);
```

Essentially, I have gathered that `WebDriver.elementLocated()` returns true as soon as the element is present in the DOM, but at this point, it is not guaranteed that the element is visible, thus the necessity to wait for this also.